# Extend cell height with labet text in tableview cell ios

Tags: ios7

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

```
NSString * message =[[chatData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"message"];
NSString * message_type = [[chatData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"message_type"];

if([[[chatData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"message_type"] isEqualToString:@"0"]){
    CGSize sizeText = [self text:message sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds) - 100, 9999) withLinebreakmode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    CGFloat heightOfRow = sizeText.height + 2 * 7.5f;
    return heightOfRow + 50;
}
else
    return 225;//message_type 1 3 4

//    return self.chatTable.rowHeight;
```

}

## pragma mark - Handling ChatLabel Width

-(CGSize)text:(NSString*)text sizeWithFont:(UIFont*)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)ConstSize withLinebreakmode :(NSLineBreakMode) linebreakmode
{
    CGSize retsize;

```
if ([text respondsToSelector:@selector(boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:)])
{
    NSMutableParagraphStyle * paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = linebreakmode;
    //  paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    NSDictionary * attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName : font,NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle};
    retsize = [text boundingRectWithSize:ConstSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading
               |NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:attributes context:nil].size;
    retsize.height =ceilf(retsize.height);
    retsize.width =ceilf(retsize.width);

    NSLog(@"%f",retsize.width);


}else{

    if ([text respondsToSelector:@selector(sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:)]){
        retsize = [text sizeWithFont:font
                   constrainedToSize:ConstSize
                       lineBreakMode:linebreakmode];
        retsize = [text boundingRectWithSize:ConstSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:nil context:nil].size;
    }
}
//[self viewWillAppear:YES];
return retsize;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

1.if you use this code,you should give only top,bottom,left and right constraint for label.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //Here you give a minimum height of the cell size.
    return 110;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```